# Refresh selected option

Tags: jquery, select, loading

I have a select tag, my jquery works perfectly fine except at the loading. At the loading an option which should be hidden is visible. But if I click on the select the option won't be available because this one is hidden (then if I select something else it becomes hidden) but it is not at the loading, why?
thanks
EDIT: I checked, every option visibility are hidden at the beginning, I have no idea why

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` in some browsers to begin with. You need to show us your code if you want help. We can't troubleshoot what we can't see

Answer (score 0):

I have this which work fine after loading:
function nextVisibleOption() {

```
function nextVisibleOption() {
    $j("#list_departement option").each(function() {

        if($j(this).is("option:visible")) {
            $j("#list_departement").val($j(this).val());
            return false;
        }
        return;
    });
}
```

And this is what I called at the beginning of the script when the page is load:

```
$j("#liste_pays_selected img").each(function() {
    var id_pays = $j(this).data("id_pays");
    $j("#lst_pays option[value=" + id_pays + "]").hide();

});
nextVisibleOption();
```

Strangely every option are considered as not visible because the script is not entering inside the if of the function nextVisibleOption..